# Is it safe to move files on Synology NAS when verifying disks?

Tags: synology

My Synology DS1812+ is performing a "Parity Consistency Check" on a new volume of 6 disks. This is taking a tremendous amount of time (~0.35% in a half hour). Can I start adding files while this is happening?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The check is done live, so you don't have to wait for it to finish if it's a routing one, though transferring the files will slow down the check and vice-versa. If you expect there is a problem with the filesystem consistency or the disks, you should not transfer files during it, and it may cause further problems.

In other words, it's best practice (and faster) to do these tasks separately, but if everything is working normally, it's fine to do them simultaneously.

Comment: To add to this old question and answer, the reason the consistency check is taking so long, is because it's been artifically slowed down to not disrupt the NAS's operation. It's deliberately running slowly, so people can keep using the server without interruptions. If you would like to speed up the process in exchange for system performance, check out this: https://gist.github.com/fbartho/2cb998dc1f10d13c124bf736286fd757